# C# Parsing XML to Lists returns empty lists

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have a problem. I am receiving the following XML from my webpage:

```
<data>
  <sets>
    <set>
      <name>Set A</name>
      <price>7.5</price>
      <pictures>
        <picture>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
          <size>1X 13X18 + 1X 10X15 + 6 pasfotos op 20X30,5</size>
          <price>7.50</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
      </pictures>
    </set>
    <set>
      <name>Set B</name>
      <price>14.45</price>
      <pictures>
        <picture>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>Potret2.jpg</name>
          <size>13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
          <size>1X 13X18 + 1X 10X15 + 6 pasfotos op 20X30,5</size>
          <price>7.50</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
      </pictures>
    </set>
    <set>
      <name>Set C</name>
      <price>13.9</price>
      <pictures>
        <picture>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>Potret2.jpg</name>
          <size>13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>2</quantity>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
          <size>13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
      </pictures>
    </set>
    <set>
      <name>Set D</name>
      <price>14.45</price>
      <pictures>
        <picture>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>GroepsFoto.jpg</name>
          <size>Groepsfoto 13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
          <size>1X 13X18 + 1X 10X15 + 6 pasfotos op 20X30,5</size>
          <price>7.50</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
      </pictures>
    </set>
    <set>
      <name>Set E</name>
      <price>21.4</price>
      <pictures>
        <picture>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>GroepsFoto.jpg</name>
          <size>Groepsfoto 13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>Potret2.jpg</name>
          <size>13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
          <size>1X 13X18 + 1X 10X15 + 6 pasfotos op 20X30,5</size>
          <price>7.50</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
      </pictures>
    </set>
    <set>
      <name>Set F</name>
      <price>21.4</price>
      <pictures>
        <picture>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>GroepsFoto.jpg</name>
          <size>Groepsfoto 13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>Potret2.jpg</name>
          <size>13 x 18 mat</size>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <quantity>2</quantity>
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <id>5</id>
          <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
          <size>1X 13X18 + 1X 10X15 + 6 pasfotos op 20X30,5</size>
          <price>7.50</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </picture>
      </pictures>
    </set>
  </sets>
  <pictures>
    <picture>
      <id>5</id>
      <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
      <sizes>
        <size>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>1X 13X18 + 1X 10X15 + 6 pasfotos op 20X30,5</name>
          <price>7.50</price>
        </size>
      </sizes>
    </picture>
    <picture>
      <id>4</id>
      <name>Potret2.jpg</name>
      <sizes>
        <size>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>13 x 18 mat</name>
          <price>6.95</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>10 x 15 mat</name>
          <price>6.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>13</id>
          <name>20 x 28 mat</name>
          <price>9.75</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>14</id>
          <name>30 x 45 mat</name>
          <price>25.00</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>15</id>
          <name>40 x 60 mat</name>
          <price>45.00</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>16</id>
          <name>50 x 70 mat</name>
          <price>57.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>17</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 20 x 28</name>
          <price>32.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>18</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 30 x 45</name>
          <price>42.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>19</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 40 x 60</name>
          <price>59.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>20</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 50 x 70</name>
          <price>72.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>21</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 60 x 80</name>
          <price>85.00</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>22</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 70 x 100</name>
          <price>99.00</price>
        </size>
      </sizes>
    </picture>
    <picture>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>GroepsFoto.jpg</name>
      <sizes>
        <size>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>13 x 18 mat</name>
          <price>6.95</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>4</id>
          <name>10 x 15 mat</name>
          <price>6.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>13</id>
          <name>20 x 28 mat</name>
          <price>9.75</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>14</id>
          <name>30 x 45 mat</name>
          <price>25.00</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>15</id>
          <name>40 x 60 mat</name>
          <price>45.00</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>16</id>
          <name>50 x 70 mat</name>
          <price>57.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>17</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 20 x 28</name>
          <price>32.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>18</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 30 x 45</name>
          <price>42.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>19</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 40 x 60</name>
          <price>59.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>20</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 50 x 70</name>
          <price>72.50</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>21</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 60 x 80</name>
          <price>85.00</price>
        </size>
        <size>
          <id>22</id>
          <name>canvas+opspannen 70 x 100</name>
          <price>99.00</price>
        </size>
      </sizes>
    </picture>
  </pictures>
</data>
```

So I created a Class that is created to parse the XML into. Here is the class I made:

```
[XmlRoot("data")]
public class MyData
{
    [XmlArray("sets")]
    [XmlArrayItem("set")]
    public List<set> Sets { get; } = new List<set>();

    [XmlArray("pictures")]
    [XmlArrayItem("picture")]
    public List<SinglePicture> Fotos { get; } = new List<SinglePicture>();
}

public class set
{
    [XmlArray("pictures")]
    [XmlArrayItem("picture")]
    public List<PictureInSet> pictures { get; set; } = new List<PictureInSet>();
    public string name { get; set; }
    public float price { get; set; }
}

public class PictureInSet
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public float price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class SinglePicture
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("sizes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("size")]
    public List<size> sizes { get; set; } = new List<size>();
}

public class size
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public float price { get; set; }
}
```

But when I am trying to parse it with the following code:

```
var xmlString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
var data = (MyData)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));

App.lstSets = data.Sets;
App.lstPictures = data.Pictures;
```

both the lists are empty. I made this class with a paste special, but changed a few things that were pasted unnecessary.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for XmlArrayItem ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute?view=netframework-4.8), the examples there all explicitly specify the type(s) of object that goes into the collection. Have you tried this:

`[XmlArrayItem (typeof(PictureInSet), ElementName = "picture")]`

Comment: Tried it, but still nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the xml you are using, these are the classes you need to use,

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "picture")]
        public class Picture
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "size")]
            public string Size { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
            public string Price { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "quantity")]
            public string Quantity { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "sizes")]
            public Sizes Sizes { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "pictures")]
        public class Pictures
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "picture")]
            public List<Picture> Picture { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "set")]
        public class Set
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
            public string Price { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "pictures")]
            public Pictures Pictures { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "sets")]
        public class Sets
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "set")]
            public List<Set> Set { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "size")]
        public class Size
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
            public string Price { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "sizes")]
        public class Sizes
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "size")]
            public List<Size> Size { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
        public class Data
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "sets")]
            public Sets Sets { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "pictures")]
            public Pictures Pictures { get; set; }
        }
```

and use the following to deserialize

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
var data = (Data)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));

List<Set> lstSets = data.Sets.Set;
List<Picture> lstPictures = data.Pictures.Picture;
```

If you are ever unsure about the classes and their structure in C#, use xml2CSharp site to generate the classes with element tags.

Comment: Okay, but what about more items from the same type, because I can't see any Lists in your class. I added my full XML to my question!?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Updated my post with working code to look up List of Set or List of Picture... you have to see the diference, Pictures is an element that has List of Picture.

Comment: It gives me the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <data xmlns=''> was not expected
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping rootMap) [0x0004f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:182`.....` What is going wrong?

Comment: I dont see any namespace tags in the xml you posted above. Not sure what xml you are working off of but the one you posted works with this code.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what value you have for the xml and which line it throws the error on.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!